# How to find the core index number which run at fastest clock via using linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, cat

for the last Intel CPU which has iTVB, for example 11700k, there are two cores can run at more 200MHz.
I want to get the index number of the core which has max clock in a system.

my script:

```
totalcores=$(nproc)
nth=$((totalcores-1))
    
printf "%d\n" "$totalcores"
printf "%d\n" "$nth"
    
echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

for((index=0; index<=$nth; index++));
do
    cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$index/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
done
```

The output will like below:

```
8
7
4900000
4900000
4900000
4900000
5012853
5006412
4900000
4900000
```

The code can output the clock of each core, but how can I get the index number for the core have max clock(it should be "5" in the case)?

#update #1
I think I had solved the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
reset

# set font color
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

# set governor to performance mode 
{
  echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
} &> /dev/null

# find the index number of the fastest core
totalcores=$(nproc)
nth=$((totalcores-1))
    
max=0
index_max=0

for((index=0; index<=$nth; index++));
do
    current=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"$index"/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq)

    if (( "$max" <= "$current" ));
      then
         max=$current
         #printf "max = %d; current = %d\n" "$max" "$current"
         #printf "before: %d\n" "$index_max"
         index_max=$index
         #printf "after: %d\n" "$index_max"
    fi
   
done

printf "The index of fastest core is: ${blue}%d${normal}\n" "$index_max"
```

Comment: First: I'd write 'performance' using a loop like you do in the second part of your script. Second: just `sort` the output and use `head`, something like `script | sort -rg | head -n1`. See `man sort` and `man head` (or use `script | sort -g | tail -n1`).

Comment: @Roadowl Thanks for you reply. My question is hope to output the index number of the fastest core, so the output should be the core index number running at  "5012853"(KHz), that should be "5" in my case. if I move the setting of governor in to the for loop and just  add | sort -rg | head -n1 to the script, the output is just a CPU core clock number.